# Android App built using KIVY fail to access Internet

Tags: python, android, kivy

I built an app using KIVY. I am using an active URL and my connection is active. 
But it shows urlerror [errno - 7]
Error in image.

I am using **urllib.request** to fetch an image. App is not crashing.

Application requirements are given below

*sqlite3, python3, kivy, urllib3, httplib2*

Permissions provided in the app are given below

*android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE*

Here is the code snippet to retrieve URL

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/img_9774_517863.jpg", "a.jpg")
```

Comment: Error as shown in logcat.                                      I python  :  socket.gaierror: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname
I python  :  urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname>

Comment: can you update your manifest file in the question , please check internet permission is there

Comment: @Jacks, the manifest file is not there, I just had buildozer spec file, where can i get it. Do I have to create a manifest file.

Comment: @jacks It worked for me I had to use http.. Certificate issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually not permission but "https"
Certificate 
I simply used http
Also including ssl certificate would work

Answer (score 0):

You also need this from this other post [Error in pytube <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72306952/error-in-pytube-urlopen-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-veri)

```
\# Solved in \
\# add\
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_stdlib_context
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35294301)