# Error in pytube <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>

Tags: python, ssl, youtube, pytube

Code:

```py
from pytube import Playlist
playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWPirh4EWFpEpO6NjjWLbKSCb-wx3hMql')

for video in playlist.videos:
    print("Video: ",video)
    video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
```

Error I am getting:

> <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>

Comment: Check the version of pytube - I test your code in Google Colab and I got no errors.

Comment: It's latest. Still getting this error. Using MAC OS

Answer (score 4):

(for OSX users)
In another words...

1. Go to your applications folder and look for Python folder. Mine says "Python 3.11"
2. Open that directory, there is a file called "Install Certificates.command".
3. Open that file and it will run the command.

Answer (score 1):

Go to /Applications/Python3.x and run 'Install Certificates.command'

Answer (score 1):

```
# Solved in 
# add
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_stdlib_context
```